# method to round to a certain amount of decimal places, according to a variable

Tags: java, math, methods

I currently have a function which will take an input and round it to 4 decimal places, it looks like this:

```
    public static double table_round(double n) {
    return (double) Math.round(n * 10000) / 10000;
}
```

really really simple function, however I was thinking I could change it to allow a second variable to be passed that says how many places to round to, however I'm not sure exactly how to go about printing the correct number of 0's in the math statement there (each 0 represents one decimal place that will be printed). Any ideas on how this could be accomplished? This is just some extra credit stuff for my java class, I'm still learning so I'm sorry if there is a simple solution I'm overlooking.

Comment: Use BigDecimal instead.. See http://www.opentaps.org/docs/index.php/How_to_Use_Java_BigDecimal:_A_Tutorial for a good tutorial over it.. And which is exactly according to your requirement..

Comment: Decimal logarithm counts the number of digits minus 1 (and can be fractional).

Comment: Ah, sorry, use `Math.round(n * Math.pow(10,n)) / Math.pow(10,n)` where `n` is your number.

Comment: @SuzanCioc's suggestion will fail badly on some inputs.  Consider: `Math.round(0.1 * Math.pow(10,20))/Math.pow(10,20) == 0.09223372036854775`.

Comment: @Robert, you are right, I forgot that `round()` returns long. The following works better: `Math.floor(0.1 * Math.pow(10,20) + 0.5d)/Math.pow(10,20)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static double table_round(double n, int digits) {
    return BigDecimal.valueOf(n).setScale(digits,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).doubleValue();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) and its [setScale()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale%28int,%20int%29) method to fix no of digits after decimal

```
public static double table_round(double n) {

    // No of digits you want after decimal.
    int digitsAfterDecimal = 5;

    BigDecimal bigDecimal = BigDecimal.valueOf(n);

    // BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR is Rounding Mode..denote how your value is rounded off
    // Other ways are:- "ROUND_CEILING", "ROUND_DOWN", etc.. 
    bigDecimal = bigDecimal.setScale(digitsAfterDecimal, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR);

    return Double.valueOf(bigDecimal.toString());
}
```

For detailed information, see http://www.opentaps.org/docs/index.php/How_to_Use_Java_BigDecimal:_A_Tutorial